# Material-UI Drawer does not scroll on mobile

Tags: css, reactjs, material-design, material-ui

I am using the [React Material UI library](http://www.material-ui.com) and have used the [Drawer](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/drawer) as a menu side-bar.

For some strange reason the drawer does not allow you to scroll on mobile devices. Here is a [link](http://acm.scorchsofttest.co.uk/).

Here is my code:

```
                 <Drawer
                    className="drawer"
                    containerClassName="drawer-container"
                    docked={false}
                    open={this.state.open}
                    zDepth={2}
                    onRequestChange={open => this.setState({ open })}>


                    <Link className="item" to="/"> <img src={acm_logo} alt="Logo" style={{ width: '100%' }} /></Link>

                    <div style={{ width: '100%' }}>
                        <MenuItem
                            className="left-menu-item" containerElement={<Link to="/" />} focusState="focused"
                            onTouchTap={this.handleClose}
                            leftIcon={<i className="material-icons md-36">dashboard</i>}>Dashboard</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem
                            className="left-menu-item" containerElement={<Link to="/emergency-waste-removal" />}
                            onTouchTap={this.handleClose}
                            leftIcon={<i className="material-icons md-36">warning</i>}>Emergency Waste
                            Removal</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem
                            className="left-menu-item" containerElement={<Link to="/terms-conditions" />} onTouchTap={this.handleClose}
                            leftIcon={<i className="material-icons md-36">description</i>}>Terms and
                            Conditions</MenuItem>
                    </div>
                </Drawer>
```

Any one know why this is happening or how I can get around this?

Comment: I'm not sure if `Drawer` uses it, but in your App did you include `react-tap-event-plugin`?

Comment: @MarkRabey Yes, I've included that in my index.js

Comment: @user3574492 did you manage to get this fixed? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue today. After much research I found that the chrome viewport height on mobile devices includes the height taken up by the address bar.

Adding few blank menu items at the bottom, fixed my scroll issue.